# HTMLCalendar displaying as a String instead of using the HTML properly (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to display an HTMLCalendar in my django project but it's only displaying the html code instead of the actual Calendar.

views.py

```
def CalendarView(request):

    cal = HTMLCalendar().formatmonth(2020, 10, withyear=True).replace('<td ', '<td  width="150" height="150"')

    return render(request, 'calendar.html', {'cal': cal})
```

calendar.html

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}

{% block tilte %} Home {% endblock %}
{% block body %}


  <div id="content-main">
          <ul class="object-tools">
            <li>
                <a href={{ previous_month }}>
                    Previous month
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href={{ next_month }}>
                    Next month
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        {{ cal }}

{% endblock %}
```

[This is what gets displayed instead of the actual calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJjsV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you would want to put instead of just `{{ cal }}`.

```
{{ cal|safe }}
```